# Validar un campo en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

este es mi codigo:

```
 from math import *
 import os
 import time
 import sys

 salir = False

 print("por favor no escribir cosas no relacionadas o el programa dara error")
 print("cargando...")

 time.sleep(3)
 os.system('cls')

 while not salir:
     numero_uno = float(input("introduce un número:"))
     os.system('cls')
     operacion = (input("\n\n'a' para realizar una suma(ejemplo: 9 + 6 = 15)\n\n'b' para realizar una resta(ejemplo: 7 - 3 = 4)\n\n'c' para realizar una multiplicación(ejemplo: 5 * 6 = 30)\n\n'd' para realizar una división 'normal'(ejemplo: 9 / 5 = 1.8)\n\n'e' para obtener el cociente(entero) de la división(ejemplo: 9 // 5 = 1)\n\n'f' para obtener solo el resto de una división(ejemplo: 9 % 5 = 4)\n\n'g' para elevar a una potencia(ejemplo: 3 ** 3 = 27)\n\nintroduce la operación a realizar:"))
     os.system('cls')
     numero_dos = float(input("introduce otro número:"))
     os.system('cls')


     if operacion == 'a':
         print(numero_uno + numero_dos)

     if operacion == 'b':
         print(numero_uno - numero_dos)

     if operacion == 'c':
         print(numero_uno * numero_dos)

     if operacion == 'd':
         print(numero_uno / numero_dos)

     if operacion == 'e':
         print(numero_uno // numero_dos)

     if operacion == 'f':
         print(numero_uno % numero_dos)

     if operacion == 'g':
         print(numero_uno ** numero_dos)

         input()
         os.system('cls')
         reiniciar = input("desea realizar otra operación? si/no: ")
         if reiniciar == "si":
         os.system('cls')

         elif reiniciar == "no":
         salir = True
```

Quiero que cuando te pida una letra solo acepte determinadas letras y sino que vuelva a pedirla.

Comment: El codigo no tiene que ver con pygame asi que esa etiqueta es inncesaria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
def input_float(msg="Ingrese un número:"):
  """Valida que el input ingresado por el usuario sea un float 
     sino vuelve a solictar el ingreso"""

  while True:
       cadena = input(msg)
       try:
          valor = float(cadena)
       except ValueError:
          print("El valor ingresado '{0}' no es un número de coma flotante! Intente nuevamente.".format(cadena))
          continue
       else:
          return valor
          break 

numero_uno = input_float("introduce un número:")
```

Acabo de definir una función `input_float` que lo que hace es solicitar al usuario el ingreso de un dato hasta que el mismo sea un valor que pueda convertirse a un `float`. Esto lo logramos mediante un ciclo infinito (`while True:`) que solo saldrá si el valor ingresado puede convertirse. Para tratar la cadena ingresada usamos un control de Excepciones, (bloque `try: .. except .. else`) en caso que una cadena no pueda transformarse en un `float` (`valor = float(cadena)`) se lanzará una excepción `ValueError` que controlamos para poder informar que el valor ingresado es incorrecto, y volvemos a repetir el ciclo. En caso que el valor ingresado sea correcto, saldremos de la función retornando el valor ya convertido a `float`.

Simplemente queda reemplazar en tu código las instrucciones de ingreso:

```
numero_uno = input_float("introduce un número:")
numero_dos = input_float("introduce otro número:")
```

Comment: y si quiero que en operación solo se permiten determinadas letras y nada más?

Comment: @ElAlien123, la lógica sería similar a la rutina que te pasé, solo debes verificar el valor ingresado, por ejemplo  `if valor in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` en cuyo caso hacer un `break` para salir del ciclo. Cualquier cosa has otra pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: podrias darme un ejemplo en codigo?

Comment: olvidalo ya lo consegui muchas gracias. Saludos.